# Does the new Android Runtime (ART) compile only Java code AOT?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, aot, android-runtime

I read about the new Android Runtime (ART) which is now the default on Android 5 (Lollipop).

I am wondering whether the Ahead of time compilation that this new runtime enables works for Java code only, or for any code ?

For example, i am writing a Mono (C#) code for Android, is that subject to any changes when being executed on the new ART ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Xamarin/Mono added support for ART in version 4.12.3 of the Xamarin Android framework.

http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_4/xamarin.android_4.12/

Comment: I am using Unity (a game engine). I don't believe they added or modified anything in their Mono runtime to support that. I was wondering if the same code may experience any issues when running on the new runtime.